# Convert fractional year and day of year to date in R

Tags: r, date, time-series

Is it possible to convert a fractional year and day of year to an actual date format in R?

For example, in the `time` column in my example data below, 1900.00 corresponds to January of 1900, 1900.08 corresponds to February.  `dayofyr` corresponds to the year day.

myData <- structure(list(time = c(1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 
1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 
1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 
1900, 1900, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 
1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 
1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 
1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.08, 
1900.08, 1900.08, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 
1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 
1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 
1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 
1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.17, 1900.25, 1900.25, 
1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 
1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 
1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 
1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 1900.25, 
1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 
1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 
1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 
1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 
1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.33, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 
1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 
1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 
1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 
1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.42, 1900.5, 1900.5, 
1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 
1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 
1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 
1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.5, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 
1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 
1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 
1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 
1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 1900.58, 
1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 
1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 
1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 
1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.67, 
1900.67, 1900.67, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 
1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 
1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 
1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 
1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.75, 1900.83, 1900.83, 
1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 
1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 
1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 
1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 1900.83, 
1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 
1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 
1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 
1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92, 
1900.92, 1900.92, 1900.92), dayofyr = 1:366), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -366L), .Names = c("time", 
"dayofyr"))

Comment: Have you checked `lubridate::date_decimal(1900.08, tz = "UTC")`?

Comment: No, I'll check it out. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `floor` to remove the decimal part, convert to a character string appending `"-01-01"`, convert that to `"Date"` class and add the number of days minus 1.  No packages are used.

```
transform(myData, date = as.Date(paste0(floor(time), "-01-01")) + dayofyr - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just messing with the floor option to remove the decimal and then paste the day of year, but this is much better solution. and works with leap years too.